# Titan Graph data migration

Tags: java, graph, cassandra, titan

I have a Java application with Cassandra 2.2.3 with Titan graph 0.5.4, and I want to migrate it to Cassandra 3.0.13. After the data migration from 2.2.3 to 3.0.13, the app doesn't start anymore with the error of

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find type for id: 630
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:200)
```

It seamed that data was corrupted, so we tried the data migration again, and again, but the same result.

Did someone try this?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [Titan 0.5.4 version compatibility chart](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/version-compat.html), that version of Titan is only compatible with Cassandra 1.2.z and 2.0.z; even if you consider [Titan 1.0.0 version compatibility](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/version-compat.html), that will only work up to Cassandra 2.1.z .

That said, Titan is no longer supported or maintained; you may wish to upgrade to [JanusGraph](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/), which supports newer versions of Cassandra, e.g., [JanusGraph versions 0.2.* and 0.3.*](https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.3.1/version-compat.html) support Cassandra 3.0.z and 3.11.z, so that should meet your use case.

JanusGraph is a fork of Titan, so it's straight-forward [to migrate from Titan to JanusGraph](https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.3.1/migrating-titan.html). For more information, see the [project website](https://janusgraph.org/) and [GitHub repo](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph), which hosts releases.

*Full disclosure: I am one of the founders of the JanusGraph project, and member of the project's Technical Steering Committee.*